# Furnace not igniting with error E228

Tags: furnace

My furnace is Armstrong Air, A97USMV, today when turn on, the induce fan keep running but not ignition, then stopped with error code E228 (Unable to perform successful pressure switch calibration).

But I don't know where is the "pressure switch", is it clogged?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pressure switch is usually part of the "inducer fan" assembly--the large black snail. Look for a vacuum tube connecting to it or nearby.

Comment: I fixed a bunch of spelling errors in your post. Please be sure that there isn't one in your model number, too. I'm having trouble finding information on that one.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks, really bad mistake! model number is A97USMV.